# How to create md5?

Tags: php

Im new in yii and I wish to md5 text get from form.

I wish to md5 string get from register form:

Something like this in controller:

```
public function register{
   $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
   $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];

   //I wish to $firtname + $lastname then md5 both as one.



}
```

I found the answer I need:
It quite easy.

```
public function register{
   $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
   $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];

   $md5 = md5($firstname.$lastname);

   print_r($md5);


}
```

Comment: md5 function doesn't really rely on that framework. just outright use that function. concatenate both string and feed it in the argument.

Comment: @Ghost hi i know how to do ady thanks

Answer (score 1):

[`md5()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.md5.php) is not related to Yii framework. So you just do

```
md5($_POST['firstname'].$_POST['lastname']);
```

It will create `md5` string. Yii itself has class [`CPasswordHelper`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CPasswordHelper) for password hashing.

```
CPasswordHelper::hashPassword($password);
```

will generate hash. Two calls to this function with same string produces different results.

To compare passwords, you than use:

```
CPasswordHelper::verifyPassword($notHashedPassword, $userModel->password);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found my own answer

```
$md5 = md5($firstname.$lastname);

print_r($md5);
```

Comment: Do you mean `md5($firstname . $lastname);` ? 2 strings do not add up.